# CreateFile in Kernel32.dll returns an invalid handle

Tags: c#, createfile, kernel32, safefilehandle

I'm trying to create a safe file handle for "C:" using the CreateFile method of kernel32.dll which always returns me an invalid handle.

Any help on what am i doing wrong here?"C:

```
CreateFile(
    lpFileName: "C:",
    dwDesiredAccess: FileAccess.ReadWrite,
    dwShareMode: FileShare.ReadWrite,
    lpSecurityAttributes: IntPtr.Zero,
    dwCreationDisposition: FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
    dwFlagsAndAttributes: FileAttributes.Normal,
    hTemplateFile: IntPtr.Zero);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare dwShareMode,
    IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

Comment: What error code do you get from `GetLastError()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of parameters not quite right.

1. To open a volume, you must prefix the drive letter with `\\.\`.
2. You can only open the volume with read privileges.

Try this code:

```
SafeFileHandle handle = CreateFile(
    lpFileName: @"\\.\C:",
    dwDesiredAccess: FileAccess.Read,
    dwShareMode: FileShare.ReadWrite,
    lpSecurityAttributes: IntPtr.Zero,
    dwCreationDisposition: FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
    dwFlagsAndAttributes: FileAttributes.Normal,
    hTemplateFile: IntPtr.Zero );
```

Note that to open a volume handle with read privileges, you *must* be running as an administrator, otherwise you will get access denied (error code 5).  As Nik Bougalis and the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation points out, if you specify `dwDesiredAccess` as 0 administrator privileges are not required.

> If this parameter is zero, the application can query certain metadata such as file, directory, or device attributes without accessing that file or device, even if GENERIC_READ access would have been denied.

Comment: Even if you are not running as an administrator you can try to open the volume with `0` for `dwDesiredAccess`. Per the [`CreateFile` page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx): "The `dwDesiredAccess` parameter can be zero, allowing the application to query device attributes without accessing a device. This is useful [...] for reading statistics without requiring higher-level data read/write permission." The returned handle is, as explained, **severely** limited, but this way you can get around the need for admin access for routine queries.

Comment: @NikBougalis thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i resolved the issue

```
    private const int GENERIC_READ = unchecked((int)0x80000000);
    private const int FILE_SHARE_READ = 1;
    private const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;
    private const int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    private const int IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX = unchecked((int)0x00070050);
    private const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
    NativeMethods.CreateFile("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE" + PhysicalDrive, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero))
```